# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or###

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, smtp, gmail, timeoutexception

1. I am writing a **python program** for **'send gamil'** but we getting errror name as ***"TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"***

**2.the program code is:**

```
import smtplib as s

ob =s.SMTP("smtp.gamil.com",587)
ob.ehlo()
ob.starttls()
ob.login('pawarpraful950@gamil.com','#######')
subject="test python"
body="I love python"
massage="subject:{}\n\n{}".format(subject,body)
listadd=['pnp950@gamil.com']
ob.sendmail('pawarpraful950@gamil.com',listadd,massage)
print("send mail")
ob.quit()
```

### 2.error is as follow:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after 
a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Please help to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following utility class which works for me:

```
import ssl
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


class Email:
    def __init__(self, server: str, port: int, address: str, password: str | None):
        self.server = server
        self.port = port
        self.address = address
        self.password = password

    def send_email(
            self, mail_to: str | list, subject: str, body: str, html: bool = False, use_ssl: bool = True
    ) -> None:
        """
        sending the email

        Args:
            mail_to: receiver, can be a list of strings
            subject: the subject of the email
            body: the body of the email
            html: whether the body is formatted with html or not
            use_ssl: whether to use a secure ssl connection and authentication

        Returns:
            None
        """
        if not isinstance(mail_to, str):
            mail_to = ', '.join(mail_to)

        if self.server == 'localhost':
            with smtplib.SMTP(self.server, self.port) as server:
                message = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
                server.sendmail(self.address, mail_to, message)
                return None
        else:
            mail = EmailMessage()
            mail['Subject'] = subject
            mail['From'] = self.address
            mail['To'] = mail_to
            if html:
                mail.add_alternative(body, subtype='html')
            else:
                mail.set_content(body)

        if use_ssl:
            with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.server, self.port, context=ssl.create_default_context()) as server:
                server.login(self.address, self.password)
                server.send_message(mail)
        else:
            with smtplib.SMTP(self.server, self.port) as server:
                server.send_message(mail)

        return None
```

You can use it like this:

```
my_email = Email(server='localhost', port=1025, address='sender@example.com', password='password')

my_email.send_email(
    mail_to=['receiver1@example.com', 'receiver2@example.com'],
    subject='Email Subject',
    body='Email Body',
    html=False,
    use_ssl=False,
)
```

This is an example using the python debugging server for visualizing email, but not actually sending them. It's very usefull for testing purposes. To start the debugging server just type `python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n localhost:1025` into a terminal or windows cli (e.g. command prompt or powershell).

To send real emails, just repalce the arguments `server` and `port` with real values and optionally use the flags `html` and `use_ssl` if you require them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as connection:
        connection.login(user='sender@gmail.com', password='XXXXX')
        connection.sendmail("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com", "Hello, World!")
```

Actually this smtplib.SMPT_SSL resolved my problem.  Gmail not allowed me to communicate over a non-SSL channel, so i used smtplib.SMTP_SSL.  Then it's worked